# Issue in starting the plugin application

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, yeoman-generator, kibana-4

My configuration's
Elasticsearch -2.0.0
Kibana -4.2.1
Node version - v5.0.0
npm version - v3.4.1

Started my elasticsearch and kibana
And followed the steps given in Kibana Plugin Yeoman Generator - Getting Started
Created a new plugin directory with yo kibana-plugin
and started using npm start

```
root@root:~/my-new-plugin$ npm start
```

it shows the following error

```
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-68-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v5.0.0
npm ERR! npm v3.4.1

npm ERR! missing script: start
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR! https://github.com/npm/npm/issues

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR! /home/guidanz-kavi/my-new-plugin/npm-debug.log
```

Found that the start script in missing in package.json.
So started using the following command

```
root@root:~/my-new-plugin$ node index.js
```

But it's exiting.

Kindly advice me to get started with the plugin.

Comment: Looks like an issue with the generated code. You should open a bug report on the kibana plugin generator repository.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In bug report I found the same error and found right way to start the application.

Answer (score 0):

Start the application using  gulp dev